# Magento - home page url

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, apache2, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

i have a two store magento installation, and i have a problem with home page's url: in both stores the home is a cms page, in cms.xml layout the route for that is cms_index_index. this seems to be a problem in one of the stores, which has a complete different layout for logged and non logged users: after loggin in, the url from www.mystore.com becomes *www.mystore.com/index.php/cms/index/index/*, if i logout the url remains *www.mystore.com/index.php/cms/index/index/*. i need that the store url remain *www.mystore.com*. how can i do that? is something that could be done with xml or other magento configuration or is something related to other (e.g. apache, rewrite,...)?

thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the template files.

There are different ways of getting the homepage url (and it's probably using one that's not helpful for you).

Here is the correct call that should be made from the templates:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

This call can be done from anywhere - just make sure to echo it.
Pesach